# Twitter API link parser

Tags: twitter, query-string

I am having an issue and tried to do everything regarding this!! even HttpUtility.ParseQueryString won't help!

I am trying to parse twitter links coming from the API in the form of http://t.co/oEVQbihMWu. I need the fully resolved URL.

My code:

```
richTextBox1.Clear();
            richTextBox1.Visible = true;
            SearchOptions SO = new SearchOptions();
            SO.GeoCode = richTextBox3.Text + "," + richTextBox2.Text + "mi";
            TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> TweetSearchResult = TwitterSearch.Search(tokens, "#blogger", SO);

            if (TweetSearchResult.Result != RequestResult.Success) richTextBox1.Text = "connection Error";
            else
            {
                string a = null;

                foreach (var tweet in TweetSearchResult.ResponseObject)
                {
                    string b = tweet.User.Location.Contains(",") ? tweet.User.Location.Replace(",", "-") : tweet.User.Location;
                    a += string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}", tweet.CreatedDate, b, tweet.User.Id,
                        tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.User.Name, tweet.User.NumberOfFollowers, tweet.User.Website, Environment.NewLine);

                    richTextBox1.AppendText(" " + tweet.CreatedDate + "\n" + tweet.User.Location + "\n" + tweet.User.Id + "\n" + tweet.User.ScreenName + "\n" + tweet.User.Name + "\n" + tweet.User.NumberOfFollowers +
                    "\n" + tweet.User.Website + "\n" + tweet.Text + "\n\n\n");



}
```

links being represented by tweet.user.website.

any help? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the API response, there is `entities.urls` which contains an array of `url` and `expanded_url` mappings. Check your library's documentation for equivalent.

Alternatively, if you inspect the response for t.co links, you will find this:

```
<noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.fitnessbydanielle.com"></noscript><title>http://www.fitnessbydanielle.com</title><script>window.opener = null; location.replace("http:\/\/www.fitnessbydanielle.com")</script>
```

Parse it to get the url.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to crack it. 
What I did:

```
foreach (var tweet in TweetSearchResult.ResponseObject)
                {
                    if(tweet.User.Website != null)
                    {
                        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(tweet.User.Website);
                        req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                        var resp = req.GetResponse();
                        string realUrl = resp.Headers["Location"];
                        string b = tweet.User.Location.Contains(",") ? tweet.User.Location.Replace(",", "-") : tweet.User.Location;
                        a += string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}", tweet.CreatedDate, b, tweet.User.Id,
                            tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.User.Name, tweet.User.NumberOfFollowers, realUrl, Environment.NewLine);

                        richTextBox1.AppendText(" " + tweet.CreatedDate + "\n" + tweet.User.Location + "\n" + tweet.User.Id + "\n" + tweet.User.ScreenName + "\n" + tweet.User.Name + "\n" + tweet.User.NumberOfFollowers +
                        "\n" + realUrl + "\n" + tweet.Text + "\n\n\n");
                    }
                }

                File.AppendAllText(@".\BloggerTable.csv", a, Encoding.UTF8);
```

}

Wrapped it inside a condition so no users without website will show and used a webrequest to get the link. stored the location inside the httprequest header for each and every tweet.